# Should I cache values in my NSTableViewDataSource / NSOutlineViewDataSource

Tags: cocoa

I'm providing an `NSOutlineViewDataSource`. Data for the table is taken out of a database. There's a small amount of processing going on, but not much.

I am calculating the value on the `outlineView: objectValueForTableColumn: byItem:` call rather than storing in the object I return from `outlineView: child: ofItem:` as the data may change often.

From initial investigations, the `NSOutlineView` hasn't done much redundant callback-ing (i.e. asked for the same row twice). I understand how the table model works and I do expect it to do a bit of this when the dataset reaches a certain size.

Should I expect a large number of redundant calls (in which case I should try and cache the data) or does it do a reasonable amount of caching itself? Does it make the call *every single time* a cell goes offscreen and then returns?

The decision of whether to cache or re-calculate is a balance between how often I expect the `objectValueForTableColumn` to be called for a given cell. Is there any consensus on which way to go? Or is it trial and error for a given dataset?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question and matches an area I am currently coding.  My own tableview reads data from an sqlite3 database so I **have** elected to cache the data (my row count can range from 1 to several million).

My cached objects also contain a *last accessed time* value so that I can clean-out the cache when it becomes too big.

One of the biggest issues I am facing is the fact that I need to `SELECT` my data based on the user's searching/sorting requirements and `NSTableViewDataSource` doesn't provide me with information about what rows are currently available.  I think I will need to subclass that sucker to add the information.

Comment: Interesting. Are you caching specific ranges or queries?

Comment: @Joe No, I simply cache whatever row is required by the tableview.  The only issue I haven't solved yet is when to remove *stale* rows from the cache.

Comment: "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.

-- Phil Karlton"

Comment: @Joe :D  I think I'll just re-order the cache by *last accessed time* and then chop off the rows over some value of *x*.